# How can I create valid connection string by using shared memory protocol to connect a named instance of sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ado.net, connection-string

How can I create a valid connection string by using shared memory protocol to connect a named instance of sql server while the sql server browser is disabled?

Answer (score 12):

The connect string format that I am using to create a connect string in a C++ application using ADO to access SQL Server through shared memory is as follows.

```
"Provider=MSDASQL;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=lpc:(local);DATABASE=%s;UID=; Password=;"
```

The `lpc:` in the `SERVER=` value forces the server connection to use the shared memory protocol.  The `%s` is used to put the specific database name into the actual control string generated from this format.

See [SQL Connect String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you use [servername][instance name], (local)[instance name] or LOCALHOST[instance name] from the local machine, it will use shared memory as long as shared memory is enabled (guiding through this in the UI is different in 2005 and 2008, so I don't know which version I should assist for).  <strike>Unlike with SQLCMD etc. there isn't a way to tell the provider that you only want to use shared memory</strike> - if for some reason it can't use shared memory it will default to a different protocol (named pipes or TCP/IP).  You can check what protocols are in use by looking at sys.dm_exec_connections:

```
SELECT session_id, net_transport 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_connections;
```

I haven't tested this with SQL Browser turned off but I think this shouldn't have any impact.  FWIW, I always use TCP/IP, but I almost always avoid having applications on the local machine that need to connect to SQL Server - this is what lower-spec'd application servers are for rather than taking memory and CPU on the database server (and therefore away from SQL Server).